# Filling empty javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a question about how a number was also associated with a string literal.

My program features a list of scorers in my game object as you can see here.

```
const game = {
    team1: 'Bayern Munich',
    team2: 'Borrussia Dortmund',
    players: [
      [
        'Neuer',
        'Pavard',
        'Martinez',
        'Alaba',
        'Davies',
        'Kimmich',
        'Goretzka',
        'Coman',
        'Muller',
        'Gnarby',
        'Lewandowski',
      ],
      [
        'Burki',
        'Schulz',
        'Hummels',
        'Akanji',
        'Hakimi',
        'Weigl',
        'Witsel',
        'Hazard',
        'Brandt',
        'Sancho',
        'Gotze',
      ],
    ],
    score: '4:0',
    scored: ['Lewandowski', 'Gnarby', 'Lewandowski', 'Hummels'],
    date: 'Nov 9th, 2037',
    odds: {
      team1: 1.33,
      x: 3.25,
      team2: 6.5,
    },
  };

let count0 = 0;
let count1 = 0;
let count2 = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < playerScored.length; i++) {
  if ( playerScored[i] === 'Lewandowski' ) {
    count0 += 1;
  }
  else if ( playerScored[i] === 'Gnarby') {
    count1 += 1;
  }
  else if ( playerScored[i] === 'Hummels') {
    count2 += 1;
  }
}




const scorers = {};
for (const player of game.scored) {
  scorers[player] ? scorers[player]++ : (scorers[player] = 1);
}
console.log(scorers);
```

My question is, in this particular line of code in the program

```
const scorers = {};
for (const player of game.scored) {
  scorers[player] ? scorers[player]++ : (scorers[player] = 1);
}
console.log(scorers);
```

How did the program show the number as well as the name of the player who scored? I kind of understand how the player name is put into the empty object. Thank you.

Comment: Do you understand what the ternary `?:` operator does?

Comment: Where is `playerScored` defined?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
  scorers[player] ? scorers[player]++ : (scorers[player] = 1);
```

is equivalent to

```
if (scorers[player]) {
    scorers[player]++;
} else {
    scorers[player] = 1;
}
```

The `if` condition checks whether the name is already in the object. If it is, it uses `++` to add `1` to the count. If the name isn't already in the object, it's created with the assignment in the `else` block, and given an initial count of `1`.

Comment: thank you for your help, but i'm confused with how it has the name as well as the number in the same line, I assume adding the ++ appends the string value with the number value as well?

Comment: it only uses `++` when the name is already in the object, so it doesn't have to append anything.

Comment: I've rewritten the answer, maybe now it's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The scorers object is something like this:

```js
scorers = {
    pique: 1,
    messi: 3,
    henry: 11
};
```

when you do `scorers[player]++` for example `scorers['pique']++` It adds one to the pique values.
and your object will become

```js
scorers = {
    pique: 2,
    messi: 3,
    henry: 11
};
```

---

and when you do `scorers[player] = 1` in your code, in fact you're adding a new property to the scorers object.
for example after  `scorers['xavi'] = 1` your object becomes:

```js
scorers = {
    pique: 2,
    messi: 3,
    henry: 11,
    xavi: 1
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `game.scored` looks like this:

```js
const game = {
  scored: ['Lewandowski', 'Gnarby', 'Lewandowski', 'Hummels']
}
```

When you run the following code:

```js
const scorers = {};
for (const player of game.scored) {
  scorers[player] ? scorers[player]++ : (scorers[player] = 1);
}
console.log(scorers);
```

It will loop through `['Lewandowski', 'Gnarby', 'Lewandowski', 'Hummels']` and checks if there is `scorers[player]`. If it exists, it just increments it by 1, otherwise, sets it to 1.

Hence, after your loop is over and you `console.log` it, `scorers` will have `'Lewandowski', 'Gnarby', 'Hummels'` as its keys.

> I'm confused with how it has the name as well as the number in the same line, I assume adding the ++ appends the string value with the number value as well

You are basically creating an object that looks like this:

```js
scorers = {
 Lewandowski: 2,
 Gnarby: 1,
 Hummels: 1
}
```

Maybe it will be easier to understand if you print the value of  `scorers` every loop.

```js
const game = {
  scored: ['Lewandowski', 'Gnarby', 'Lewandowski', 'Hummels']
}

const scorers = {};
for (const player of game.scored) {
  scorers[player] ? scorers[player]++ : (scorers[player] = 1);
  console.log(scorers);  
}
```